# How long can we use DeprecatedHeaders in Facebook SDK 3.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, apprequests

I need to send an invitation from my iOS app to friends. I know that I can do it with "apprequests" and dialog, but this option is good only when we use "DeprecatedHeaders". 
How long can we use DeprecatedHeaders in Facebook API? Are they going to support it in the future?
Is there any option to send invitation to friends from iOS app?

I prefer using SDK 3.1 than older one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.2 of the Facebook SDK was released on 2/24 and this addresses the deprecated issue.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.2/

And the upgrade guide if you need it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.1-to-3.2/